# Composite controls: Render vs CreateChildControls

Tags: asp.net

I am learning creating Composite controls with UI design-time support.

There are 2 ways to implement it:
 Overriding Render - and in this case open and close html tags.
 Overriding CreateChildControls  - and in this case create controls with their properties and add them to control collection.

Which one is better and efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good article that answers your question [A Crash Course on ASP.NET Control Development: Building Composite Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479016.aspx).

The summary is to use Render for read-only controls, nothing interactive. Use CreateChildControls for anything that requires event handling or posted data.